# MSSQL/PHP using case statement on null entries when inserting

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, null, case

I have an issue where I need to insert a value in a date field in MSSQL. I'm while'ing through a PHP script and inserting from one database to another - some of the date values will be null. However MSSQL gives me an error when inserting as when using a PHP variable as the insert, it comes out as an empty string, which is inserted as 1900-01-01 as a date and not null. I want to insert null where the date is null.

I need to insert null in place of the value and have tried a case statement thus:

```
echo var_dump($member['FW_RenewalDate']).'<br/>';
                    if( $member['FW_RenewalDate']!=''){
                        $member['FW_RenewalDate'] = "'".str_replace(" 00:00:00", "", $member['FW_RenewalDate'])."'";
                    }else{
                        echo 'here';
                        $member['FW_RenewalDate'] = null;
                    }
$sql = "INSERT INTO MemberStatus
                                ( mbr_id, start_date, end_date, minute_ref, sponsor, member_type, categoryid, updated_date, updated_by )
                                VALUES ( '{$member['MBR_ID']}', null, 
                                CASE WHEN {$member['FW_RenewalDate']} IS NULL THEN null ELSE {$member['FW_RenewalDate']} END, 
                                null, '{$member['FW_Sponsor']}', '{$typeResult['MT_ID']}', '{$categoryResult['id']}', '$now', '$crsid' )";
```

```
INSERT INTO MemberStatus ( mbr_id, start_date, end_date, minute_ref, sponsor, member_type, categoryid, updated_date, updated_by ) VALUES ( '1118', null, CASE WHEN IS NULL THEN null ELSE END, null, '', '5', '7', '2023-10-17 15:14:40', 'djt63' )
```

ERROR ADDING CONTENT: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'. [20018] (severity 15) [INSERT INTO MemberStatus ( mbr_id, start_date, end_date, minute_ref, sponsor, member_type, categoryid, updated_date, updated_by ) VALUES ( '1118', null, CASE WHEN IS NULL THEN null ELSE END, null, '', '5', '7', '2023-10-17 15:14:40', 'djt63' )]

The PHP variable $member['FW_RenewalDate'] is the one I'm trying to test for null - it seems to work, but as I've set it to null it comes out as empty in the case statement.

Comment: If you would parameterize your SQL statement properly, you wouldn't have such issues. Do **not** inject data into queries as text, it's **dangerous**. Eitehr way, not sure, what else you expected: a `null` value is not the same as a `"null"` string.

Comment: It's a one-off script that will be disposed of afterwards, but I will test parameterizing

Comment: Still, that is the root cause of your issue. Yes you could patch it up by using `if` to check for `null` but you will end up with more issues.

Comment: Sorted, thanks. I'm always coming across date field issues in MSSQL and went down the wrong route. Thanks for your hint.